# Animation splash screen of toolbar resizing

Tags: android, animation, toolbar, splash-screen

**EDIT2**

Everything works now, except for floating action button's onclick listener doesn't work.

---

**EDIT**

Ok so i've come with a semi-solution
I've removed AppBarLayout from **activity_main.xml**, and now it does not flicker anymore. The only thing is that the action bar is completely white, and does not merge with the toolbar color. How could i fix this?

---

I've followed [this](http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts) site in order to achieve this animation(without recycler view though):

[image]

The only thing is that mine is flickering a lot and I don't know where could be the issue. Also the toolbar gets to small than the default size. Thank you

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
private CoordinatorLayout main_content;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private int mContentViewHeight;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_main_activity));
    main_content = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);/*
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BasicActivity.class));
        }
    });*/
    // Fake a long startup time
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onFakeCreate();
        }

    }, 100);
}

    private void onFakeCreate() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding_placeholder);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        ViewCompat.animate(titleTextView).alpha(1).start();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                        mToolbar.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
                        mContentViewHeight = mToolbar.getHeight();
                        collapseToolbar();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    private void collapseToolbar() {
        int toolBarHeight;
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
        toolBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        ValueAnimator valueHeightAnimator = ValueAnimator
                .ofInt(mContentViewHeight, toolBarHeight);

        valueHeightAnimator.addUpdateListener(
                new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        mToolbar.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }
                });

        valueHeightAnimator.start();
        valueHeightAnimator.addListener(
                new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                        // Animate fab
                        ViewCompat.animate(fab).setStartDelay(600)
                                .setDuration(400).scaleY(1).scaleX(1).start();

                    }
                });
    }
[...]
```

**Splash_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque"
    >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/background"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:height="180dp"
        android:gravity="top">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**activity_main.xml(updated)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="156dp"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Android mainifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BasicActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_basic"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ExtraActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_extra"
            android:parentActivityName=".BasicActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: its working at my side toolbar size is also normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the style in your project.toolbar animation working fine at my side.

```
    <resources>
    <style name="Button" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/indigo_500</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/pink_200</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

also check the build gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Hope this helps.:)

Comment: Thank you. Before you commented i ran out of patience and deleted everything but you gave me the will to try again. I did it again from scratch in the most clean possible way and it actually works now. I think it's because i didnt create and set "AppTheme.Placeholder". The only thing now is that fab's onclicklistener doesn't work anymore. also menu buttons on action bar are gone. Could you help me? thanks ***edit*** ok i've fixed the menu issue using setSupportActionBar(toolbar); fab onclicklistener issue still is there tho

Comment: one problem with this.after renter in app the animtion not working.:)

Comment: fab is overlaping with the other views i.e onFakeCreate()fuction

Comment: okay i thought about, but how can i fix it? thanks
***edit*** okay fixed it. i've put onclicklistener inside onFakeCreate()

Comment: one more thing: fab animation is not working with me like in the picture. even if the code is exactly the same. is it working with you?

Comment: never mind, had to add android:scaleX="0" and android:scaleY="0" to the fab in the layout, just as the source project.